# Can in C++ override a virtual method by calling a method from a private instantiated class without reimplementing it?

Tags: c++, function, overriding, virtual

sorry updated

I have a class A that overrides many methods from another class B and beside it has an instance of the class B from which I want the methods to be called. B is an interface with virtual methods so it has an implementation passed to me via pointer
i.e.
class B

```
class B{
public:
  virtual int f1(int x);
  virtual int f2(int x)
}
```

then I have other classes which implements B, let's say C, D and E which also have other interfaces.

then I have the class A which has a pointer to a class that implements B besides other thing.

I need to override the methods in a manner like the following one

and class A

```
class A:
  public B
{
private:
  B* b;
public:
  A(B* _b){
    b = _b;
  }
  int f1(int x) override
  {
    return b->f1(x);
  }
      
  int f2(int y) override
  {
    return b->f2(y);
  }
}
```

Is it possible to avoid the overriding of each method by allowing the compiler to call the methods from the implementation?

Comment: `B* b;` isn't necessary at all, `this` should be fine.

Comment: If you remove b, your overrides are not necessary.

Comment: One big proplem here is the fact that `f1` and `f2` are private in `B`. `A` won't be able to access them one way or another unless you add a friend declaration to `B`.

Comment: So it's basically a [pimpl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl), right? No I don't think you can do that automatically.

Comment: Do you want the compiler to be able to generate your `A::f1` and `A::f2` that calls `b`'s methods automatically or what are you asking? Your current setup would work with some additions and corrections. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/s1a39rzf6)

Comment: yes @TedLyngmo I want something like that, is it possible to avoid rewrite every function?

Comment: No, see Bill's answer.

Comment: @Jarod42 does it calls the function from the implementation of the class?

Comment: Unrelated: Make `A`'s constructor like I showed in the example: `A(B& bref) : b(&bref) {}` since you don't want to allow `nullptr`.

Comment: @ste93: Your class `A` has 2 `B`s currently (the base class, and a member), so it is unclear what you want. but with the using, the base class method would be public from `A` interface.

Comment: @ste93 What is the purpose of `A`? You could make another class that inherits from whatever derived type `b` is pointing at right now instead, right? Or are these relationships built in runtime? In that case, what does `A` do that can't be done directly by the object `b` is pointing at?

Comment: @Jarod42: I want that A exposes B interfaces (base class that are virtual) and this call must be forwarded to member's method (b), but as bill says I think there is no way to do it

Comment: @ste93 I still don't get what role `A` has. Why not use the instance that `b` is pointing at directly instead of an instance of `A`? I have a feeling that there's a simpler solution to what it is you want to achieve. Perhaps [this](https://godbolt.org/z/7qGPq9fzY)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call `f1()` and `f2()` on the member variable, then no. There is no automatic mechanism to tell the compiler that calls to `A::f1()` should be forwarded to `b->f1()`.

Comment: Ok thank you Bill , I was supposing it but I was hoping there was a good method to do it.